# How change state in child from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to Reacts. I read a lot post and I can not find a solution to my problem.

**Task:** 
Do so that inside each `<td>` there was an 'edit' button, by clicking on which the text of this `<td>` can be edited with the `<input />` of the appeared in it.

**Parent:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BehaviorInput from './BehaviorInput';

class BehaviorTable extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            users: [
                {name: 'Коля', age: 30},
                {name: 'Вася', age: 40}
            ],
            status: false
        }
    }
    handlerEdit = (key, value) => {
        if (isNaN(value)){
            this.state.users[key].name = value;
        }else{
            this.state.users[key].age = value;
        }
        this.setState({
            'users': this.state.users,
        });
    };
    render(){
        return(
            <table>
                <tbody>
                {this.state.users.map((item, index) => (
                    <tr key={index}>
                        <td>
                            {item.name}
                            <BehaviorInput
                                status={this.state.status}
                                value={item.name}
                                index={index}
                                editFn={this.handlerEdit}
                            />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {item.age}
                            <BehaviorInput
                                status={this.state.status}
                                value={item.age}
                                index={index}
                                editFn={this.handlerEdit}
                            />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
}
export default BehaviorTable;
```

**Child:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class BehaviorInput extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            'status': this.props.status,
            'value': this.props.value
        }
    }
    callChangeName(event){
        this.setState({
            'value': event.target.value
        });
    }

    handlerChange(){
        this.setState({'status': !this.state.status});
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <p>
                {(this.state.status) ?
                    <input type="text"
                           value={this.state.value}
                           onChange={this.callChangeName.bind(this)}
                           onBlur={this.props.editFn.bind(null, this.props.index, this.state.value)}
                    />:
                    <button
                        onClick={this.handlerChange.bind(this)}
                    >Edit</button>
                }
            </p>
        )
    }
}

export default BehaviorInput;
```

I don't understand how change state in child component from parent component?
Maybe I think wrong. Please give me an advice on my problem.

Comment: It does not look like you need to have state in your children. What you could is just make a way for the children to update the state of the parent (by passing a function in the props) and then keeping all your state inside of your parent.

Comment: create a so-called state array in the parent?

Answer (score 0):

I just came across a similar problem recently, where I wanted to change a child based on a button click on the parent.  The button being clicked is in the parent's render method, along with the click handler, and the child props are passed to the child from the parent's state.  This way the child is updated automatically, although it isn't a state being updated, I don't think.  I haven't used react very long - so anyone feel free to correct me on that.  I have a codepen here that demonstrates what I mean, where clicking any day of the week updates the detailed view.

https://codepen.io/Macpeters/pen/dJZoLM

The parent has a week (array) and day.  The day is updated with whatever day of the week was clicked.  It then passes the day to the detail component

```
   <div>  
      <h1>7 Day Weather Forcast:</h1>
       {week.map(function(day, index){
          return <span key={ index }>
            <a href="#"
              onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, index)}
              ><Card day={day}/></a></span>;
       })}
      <div><DetailedCard day={week[details]}/></div>
    </div>
```

The detail component then refers to the day in its props

```
   <div>
    <h3>Detailed Forecast for {this.props.day.date} </h3>
    <span><img src={this.props.day.image} /> 
    High of {this.props.day.high}, Low of {this.props.day.low}</span>
    <p>{this.props.day.description}</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the decision on my problem.
In child component add new function were change state in child and call other function.

```
changeCall() {
        this.handlerChange();
        this.props.editFn(this.props.index, this.state.value, this.props.objectKey);
    }
```